# jQuery style function defaults using objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, function

I have a project that I am working on where I am not able to use jQuery. Since using jQuery, I have become very acustomed to the way that parameters can be set in a function.  It is very nice doing it the "jQuery" way, so that it does not matter the order, or even if you use all defaults like a normal function method would need.

So, my question is how would I turn like this:

```
function myFunction(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5) {

}
```

To a jQuery like method, without using jQuery:

```
function myFunction({
 param1: 'test',
 param2: 'test2'
});
```

Any help on this would be great!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want to define a single *options* argument in your function, and extend it against a *default values* object:

```
function myFunction (options){
  options = extend({ // default values
    param1: 'test',
    param2: 'test2'
  }, options || {});

  alert(options.param1);
}

// helper function to "extend" the 'b' object from 'a'
// by copying its properties
function extend(a, b) {
  for ( var prop in b ) {
    a[prop] = b[prop];
  }
  return a;
}
```

Then if you call:

```
myFunction ({param1:'overriden!'});
```

`options.param1` will be overriden within your function, and `options.param2` will remain with its default value "test2".

Comment: +1 You wrote your answer faster and more succinctly than me. Good work